# Apple id security questions not allowing me to download apps

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, security

I bought an iPhone 4S. I am trying to download apps from the App store but it is not letting me do it. Every time I try to download an app, a window pops up asking me to type in my Apple ID password. When I enter my password another window pops up asking me to answer to three security questions. If I click on continue it keeps on asking me to enter the password. I have already answered one security question (as there is only one question) by going on appleid.apple.come manually. It still is not working. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue - I cannot buy apps from my phone (i can install free ones).  I can however buy them in iTunes on my computer and the iPhone 4s will download and install them...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried resetting your phone? Otherwise known as Powering Off ... and then, like, On again.

"Hold down Sleep/Wake button and Home button for at least 10 seconds, until the Apple logo appears."

(Direct quote from Apple graphic, as seen on Gizmodo, in an attempt to thin down the Genius Bar crowds.)

Answer (score -1):

The guy that said to turn off your phone doesn't know what he is talking about. Okay so I have the same problem. If you don't have any money on your account that you wouldnt risk losing, then reset your phone with a new apple ID. To do that, go to your general settings and there should be a reset button somewhere on there. Another thing you can do is schedule a call with apple and talk to them about it, that's the only other option that I know of.

Comment: Just so you know, having multiple Apple IDs can cause FairPlay/authorization headaches in the future.